# List level or indexing question when using ApendTo on two lists

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I am unsure about the "level" I am using to concatenate to lists. My use case is

```
OddBeforeEven3[list : {__Integer}] := 
 Module[{results, evens}, results = {}; evens = {};
  Do[If[! EvenQ[i], AppendTo[results, i], AppendTo[evens, i]], {i, 
    list}];
  AppendTo[results, evens];
  Return[results]]
```

I want

`{1, 3, 2, 4}`

but get

`{1, 3, {2, 4}}`

What is this issue called and how do I solve it? I imagine it is a form of indexing problem I have here. This would help me a lot, working on the Wolfram Challenges, see

https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/challenge/odds-before-evens

Comment: One way to go from lists like {1, 3, {2, 4}} to {1, 3, 2, 4} would be to use Flatten.

Comment: or use `AppendTo[results, #] & /@ evens`  (or `results = Join[results, evens]`) instead of `AppendTo[results,  evens]`.

Comment: try  `oddBeforeEven = SortBy[{EvenQ}]`

Answer (score 1):

You may use "Sort" with a sorting function. This function should return -1 if an even number appears before an add number and 1 in the opposite case like:

```
Which[OddQ[#1] && EvenQ[#2], 1, OddQ[#2] && EvenQ[#1], -1] &
```

Now e.g.:

```
d = Range[10];
Sort[d, Which[OddQ[#1] && EvenQ[#2], 1, OddQ[#2] && EvenQ[#1], -1] &]

1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
```